# Best way to output a list of months in a Twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig

What is the best way to output a list of months in a Twig template? For example creating a month drop down in a date of birth set of fields. The format I am after is:

```
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple loop of 12 to create a date string for each month, then run that through Twig's date filter like below:

```
{% for month in 1..12 %}
    {% set date = month ~ "/1/2016" %}
    <option value="{{ date|date("m") }}">{{ date|date("F") }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

This results in the requested format:

```
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
```

The format can easily be changed using [php's date format options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

TwigFiddle of example [here](http://twigfiddle.com/hy06aq).

Answer (score 3):

The form component actually do it, you just need to set format:

```
$builder->add('birth_date', DateType::class, ['format' => 'ddMMMMyyyy']);
```

The output is:

```
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
...
```